# Thread identification

Tags: mechanical-engineering, threads

I am having a very difficult time identifying this thread. This part is a plug that I am trying to replace because the threads were stripped.

The best fit for pitch is 11 threads per inch (imperial), but the major thread diameter is 32mm. It does not appear to be tapered and the rubber seal would support this observation.

I have looked through many standard thread size charts and have been unable to locate a match. I thought BSPP-16 was close enough (at 33mm) but when I tried, the BSPP plug was too large to fit the associated female thread.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming you can't contact the company who makes the part?

Comment: Are you able to say what type of equipment that the plug goes in to?

Comment: @JMac I have not been able to get any information from the manufacturer.

Comment: @GlenH7 This is the cap to a dry-sump oil reservoir for a Japanese-made HKS engine. I think the reservoir and this cap may have been an off-the-shelf solution from another manufacturer.

Comment: That does not look like 11 threads per inch - "just" matches the right hand two, but the left hand looks to have an increasing space...

Comment: @SolarMike the picture was hard to take correctly since I had to hold that with one hand. The gauge is not at a right angle to the threads. I also checked 10 and 11.5 as well as metic 2.0 and 2.5. This was the correct one.

Comment: M32 Threads come in standard pitches of 2.0mm and 1.5mm - 11 TPI is closer to 2.3mm, so if the 2.0 gauge didn't fit, then it's not an "M Thread".

Comment: I tried a 1" NPT and it was really close. I am thinking that maybe it's a 1" BSPT